# Programmatic launching of installed app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Does the Windows Phone SDK have support for the launching of another install application? I'm not seeing any documentation. On android I'm aware of intent so this is different.

Answer (score 3):

The naive answer is "No, the WP doesn't allow to start another application".
But if application has a [registered file or URI association](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you can use [Windows.System.Launcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.system.launcher.aspx) to launch it